# Question from number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a, b, \text{and } c$ are integers with $0 < a < b < c$ and $\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1$.

Show that one of the follows holds,

- $\gcd(a,b)=1$ or
- $\gcd(a,c-b)=1$ or
- $\gcd(c-a,b)=1$ or
- $\gcd(c-a, c-b)=1$.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: It would really help to know what you have tried so far and if you've made any progress. As a general hint, when trying to prove an 'or', try to show that one equality is true while assuming that at least one of the others are false.

Comment: Hi Jacob, Many thanks for editing. I tried to solve it by induction on n=a+b+c, but failed.

Comment: c-a=211-120=91, and gcd{c-a, b}= gcd{91, 190}=1. Am I right dear user14111?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $a=36,b=190,c=211$.